# Display filters in the "Hot questions" sidebar

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I have a [hot questions filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/116117/my-filter) that consist of the sites I'm interested in.

It'd be cool if I didn't have to go to this page to see the filter, as most of the cool network questions I see are just because I glanced at the side.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your filter is not related to hot questions. It filters all the questions.

Comment: Well then there should be a way to filter the hot questions.

Comment: [That's right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/filter-hot-network-questions-by-excluding-sites). :)