# How do I delete "CodeGolf" from my list of questions when I go to stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, tag-filters

I've tried clicking "My Filter" and editing Code Golf out, but it still shows up. I find the questions from this particular community really bad. (think when Reddit had /r/politics and /r/atheism as defaults).

Anyway, can someone help me delete Code Golf from the feed when I go to the TLD?

Comment: As a moderator on Code Golf, I am very genuinely sorry you feel that way about the community. If you have any specific concerns I invite you to post on the Code Golf Meta site. I'd love to be able to change your opinion of the site.

Comment: @AlexA., Hi Guy!   No, don't be genuinely sorry that I hate your site.  None of us can please everyone, and we should just do our best with our endeavors and realize it's impossible to please everyone (we'll go crazy trying).  Keep up the good work - I just can't wait until I never have to see it on StackExchange :-) Also, I'd be happy to try to give you some constructive criticism on your site, but there doesn't seem to be a private method for PMing on SE and I don't really want to deal with all the hate from spectators, so sorry!  I guess we can both just chalk it up to personal taste.

Comment: I think you would be doing the Code Golf community a great service by providing any constructive critism you have to offer. If you plan to delete your CG account anyway, you can post to our Meta first, then you won't be notified of replies and other activity once your CG account is deactivated. Regardless of what you choose to do, I hope the rest of the Stack Exchange network is able to better serve your interests than CG has been able to.

Comment: @AlexA. [Done](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6983/why-i-am-leaving-code-golf).

Comment: Thank you very much for providing your feedback, it is much appreciated. Hopefully the community will be able to learn and grow from your experiences, and perhaps one day you'll return (though I won't count on it ;)). Until then, on behalf of the Code Golf community, I bid you a fond farewell.

Comment: i do understand your feelings, but it is just kind of love&hate relation that has ups and downs, flips and flops. Do mind that i felt exactly that way but i do not care anymore if some wonderful places in this server happen to have some very unfriendly members.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text on the filter says:

> View questions from all Stack Exchange sites you have an account on

That means that the only way to remove that community from the *Filtered Questions > My sites* list is to [delete your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/245360) there.

I do wonder though why you want to hide *your own* questions from the list. Isn't that just your contribution? If you are angry, just let it go and keep constructive.

Maybe you should post your worries on the meta of CodeGolf als moderator Alex A. proposed you in his comment.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I didn't see an automatic way to delete the account (I didn't even know I made one on Code Golf), so I just sent a message to Stackexchange to delete just the Code Golf one.  Thanks for your help.  -----  P.S.  I didn't mean to hide my own questions, I just meant I wanted all of Code Golf to go away on my feed.  Apparently, I made an account and that's why it has been showing up, but I don't remember doing it and didn't see an option to hide the posts, which is why I'm posting this long ass run on sentence  :-)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution would be to install [Stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus) or a similar user CSS manager, and add the following user style for stackexchange.com:

```css
.question-container[data-sid="codegolf.stackexchange.com"] { display: none }
```

This will hide any questions from codegolf.SE from the Filtered Questions list, as well as from the SE.com front page and other similar lists.

---

Bonus: The following user CSS, applied to any SE sites you visit, will also hide codegolf.SE from the Hot Network Questions sidebar:

```css
#hot-network-questions a[href*="//codegolf.stackexchange.com/"],
#hot-network-questions .favicon.favicon-codegolf { display: none }
```

<sup>(I'm kind of tempted to apply this to puzzling.SE myself.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the alternative idea.  It might not work for me for most cases because I use *many* computers to browse SE (mostly different boxes in the lab) and I have a bad habit of wiping my OS from time to time.  Still, if I ever start using a dedicated box I will keep this comment in mind.