# Any way to hide questions in Hot Network Questions, based on tag

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, filtering, spoilers, hot-tab

(Specific issue topic: Game Of Thrones questions. Askers and Question Editors here do try v. hard to make the question titles non-spoiler-y but it's not perfect and I'd prefer not to se the titles.)

I like browsing the Hot Network Questions, because they're often interesting and occasionally I can contribute something.

But there are some question tags that I don't want to see.

Is there any way to prevent them from appearing to me? (Either in the list on the RHS of the screen, or on the dedicated page.
Ideally this filter would be based on a tag, though I would probably take "blocking a whole exchange site" if need be?

Comment: It's possibly to [hide questions from a specific site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266244) in the HNQ sidebar with a [user style](https://userstyles.org/help/other), but there's no practical way to make that tag-specific (because the sidebar doesn't show tags). Still, if you're desperate to avoid GoT spoilers, you could always just hide all HNQs from [scifi.SE].

Comment: [The top user at SFF has provided an artist's impression of a great way to hide the HNQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAQdc.jpg)

Comment: Spoiler filtering is too user specific. Use a browser addon, after all you want to avoid GoT spoilers on any site, not just SE, right? [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224108/prevent-questions-with-movie-tv-shows-game-spoilers-from-appearing-in-the-hot-qu/300343#300343)

Comment: Should this be tagged feature-request?

Answer (score 1):

A good technical solution would be to allow mods to exclude questions from specific tags from appearing on the HNQ.

Impact would be low, since filtering is not done per user, so it does not have to take each user's preferences into account. This would simply prevent questions within a tag from reaching the HNQ *at all*.

### Use Cases

#### Foo

Users on Stack *Foo* have learned (the hard way) that subject *Bar* is poorly understood by laypeople, drawing bad answers and needing protection whenever a question about Bar hits the HNQ.

Mods on *Foo.SE* add [bar](/questions/tagged/bar) to the list of HNQ-banned tags. Questions tagged with it no longer reach the HNQ and no longer draw as many bad answers.

#### Movies & TV

A new M. Night Shyamalan film, *Foo in the Land of Bars*, has come out. People would like to see it without having the twist and double-twist ending spoiled for them, but people who have already seen the film are asking questions left and right, not always being careful with the titles.

Mods on Movies.SE add [foo-in-the-land-of-bars](/questions/tagged/foo-in-the-land-of-bars) to the list of HNQ-banned tags. Questions tagged with it no longer reach the HNQ and no longer spoil other users.

#### Quux

A question on the new Quux Beta has reached the HNQ, but is actually a bad representation of Quux.SE. There's discussion in the Quux chatroom and on Quux.meta.SE if the question should be closed. Meanwhile, users across the network are getting their first impressions of the Quux Beta through that question.

Mods pro-tem on Quux.SE add [exclude-from-hnq](/questions/tagged/exclude-from-hnq) to the list of HNQ-banned tags and tag the contentious question with it. This questions is dropped from the HNQ and the new users of Quux.SE can discuss its topicality without fear of leaving the wrong impression across the network.

Comment: **-1** I, like many users, wish to avoid reading spoilers, but banning an entire tag for that sounds a bit too extreme to me. I think it's enough that we edit the titles to avoid spoilers. Or setup filters to hide certain tags for each user as per their tastes.