# Only hot questions in feed from sites I have an account for

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-feed

In the android app, it would be great if you could choose if you wanted to see only hot questions from the sites you are registered on in your **Feed**, or (as it is the case now) to see all hot questions from all networks. I'm mainly active on *StackOverflow* and honestly I don't currently care that much about for example *The Great Outdoors* or *Academia*, so I think this feature would be quite welcome.

Comment: Related: [Filter "Hot Network Questions" by excluding sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/filter-hot-network-questions-by-excluding-sites)