# Is it possible to filter/blacklist SE sites?

Tags: support, hot-questions

So many questions show up on the right side of the page (Popular Questions) i.e:

[image]

So I was wondering if it is possible to filter these questions to only display the ones that I'm interested in seeing.

Also, it would be cool if we can do the same to the list of SE on the top of the page.

[image]

Comment: not sure about the first one but the second one you can already do. in that list above "more stack exchange communities" you have "your communities" with an "edit" link which you can add and remove sites.

Comment: @Memor-X, wah. ty

Comment: There is no official way to filter hot network questions. Several users have written user scripts/browser plugins that include this functionality. [Here's mine for Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272128/134300), and here are related threads where you can find others: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84389/134300, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225297/134300, https://superuser.com/q/1157967/7301

Comment: @JeremyBanks awesome. Off topic. Is there a way I can stay up to date with newly launched SE sites ?

Comment: It looks like [Area 51 has a RSS feed of sites in beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/beta), which you could subscribe to to learn about new ones as they launch. I don't know of any better way.