# Sidebar movie spoilers

Tags: bug, sidebar

While visiting technical sites to do my job I'm also learning spoilers from movies I want to see. Can you fix this? Current one pertains to movies.stackexchange.com and Infinity War.

Comment: Also: [Filter “Hot Network Questions” by excluding sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/filter-hot-network-questions-by-excluding-sites?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: [We're just trying to ensure that you experience the most enjoyment possible when finally you do see the movie.](https://www.universityofcalifornia.edu/news/spoiler-alert-spoilers-make-you-enjoy-stories-more)