# Confusion about hiding communities in your profile and hiding sites from HNQ

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, user-experience

I figured it might be possible to hide unwanted SE sites from Hot Network Questions, and after a few clicks through profile/settings I thought I had found out where to do it, but it turns out I'd misread and that feature did something else. Apparently there is [a previous request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/filter-hot-network-questions-by-excluding-sites) for this with `staus-deferred`, but I don't think previous requests have done an adequate job of presenting motivations for the feature.

The reason I was looking for this is that it occurred to me that certain sites frequently have question titles that might be serious microaggressions/triggers (especially Skeptics, which often cites claims made by hate movements, and to a much lesser extent also Workplace and Academia), and many users might want to avoid that kind of content while using Stack Exchange sites.

Could the description of the "Hide Communities" profile tab be clarified to state explicitly that it doesn't hide things from Hot Network Questions? Could the deferred feature request for the ability to hide unwanted sites from HNQ be re-opened and completed, ideally with notification that you can do so and a link to do it right under the HNQ heading?

Comment: That's not what that does

Comment: You can't hide sites from HNQ.  Are you talking about hiding communities on your profile?

Comment: You're mixing things up; hiding communities on your profile does not influence the HNQ.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would also hide them from HNQ. I misunderstood totally then. Is there any way at all to hide them from HNQ?

Comment: Apart from installing userscripts, no.

Comment: (If not, the question should be changed or resubmitted as a request to let you hide things from HNQ)

Comment: @Glorfindel: I think it's at least partly/largely duplicate, but the original question lacks the feature request and motivation for why it should be added (frequent microaggressions).

Comment: What's the right course of action in this case? Try to edit or comment the request/motivation into the cited question this duplicates? Or keeping the request separate here?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/filter-hot-network-questions-by-excluding-sites) is the original request, which has been marked as "deferred". To try and prevent the dupe votes here, you should link to it here and provide a clear argument that you're aware of it and believe that it should be completed in light of new circumstances.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Thanks. I've edited the question with a link and further changes to the text to acknowledge previous ones.

Comment: @Glorfindel This question has since been edited; please consider casting a reopen vote.