# Customizable HNQ lists, but better

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

> **Note:**
>
> Surprisingly, only 2 questions seem to mention customized HNQs:
>
> - [Should Hot Network Questions (HNQs) be customizable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324359/should-hot-network-questions-hnqs-be-customizable)
> - [Filter "Hot Network Questions" by excluding sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/filter-hot-network-questions-by-excluding-sites)
>
> The first is closed as a duplicate of the second, and both seem to request filtering of HNQs. One has a userscript to do this. This is not another version of the same request.

Hot Network Questions seem to have been an important topic in (relatively) recent meta discussions: the removal of IPS.SE (and its reintroduction), moderator removal of HNQs, etc. Surprisingly, despite years of their existence, there hasn't been a single step towards client-side customization of HNQs.

**Why not?**

There doesn't seem to be much of an explanation for this. Not a single answer on any of the two above related questions, beyond workarounds with userscripts.

**Filtering isn't the solution:**

Filters, while a nice start, wouldn't be quite what the site needs. A filter, by definition, only removes items. It would make more sense for more items to be added as more are removed, to keep the HNQ list populated. A better solution would be user-tailored HNQs:

1. A certain algorithm would create a list of the top ±20 questions on each SE site
2. When a user opens a page, their allowed and disallowed sites are read (defaults to all sites based in the language the user is using)
3. Another algorithm chooses what questions from the remaining list are sent

**Issues:**

One issue could be performance. However, since the slow part (creating the top-20 lists) would be done once every few minutes/hours on the sever side, it wouldn't delay the user experience. The time it takes for a database of user preferences to be read may add a bit of delay, but I wouldn't expect it to be much of a penalty on load time.

**Other improvements:**

Not only could site filtering be an option, but the server's lists could also have additional filtering like what is currently in place for languages. The user could also potentially choose how many HNQs to display, or assign weights to certain sites. Some fancy tag-based filtering might even be possible, allowing users to ensure that they're only showed SO questions in their preferred languages, or Sci Fi/Fantasy questions about a certain series they've read.

**Why we need it:**

- So someone using Stack Exchange purely for a few sites can find questions which interest them faster or are answerable by them
- So one doesn't accidentally read a spoiler due to a vague title on a question
- To reduce drive-by voting/commenting on topics which the user is not capable of providing genuine help
- So certain overrepresented sites can be tweaked by personal preferences to only show up on occasion
- So users aren't swamped with HNQs about topics they do not understand in any way, which are then useless for that user

**Optimization:**

- The lists could be stored as single `CHAR(120)` entries per site, containing a base 64 encoded question ID
- The filtered list could be created using the question IDs, and only about 20 question names would have to be looked up, compared to 30,000+
- A cached filtered list could be created for any users which are currently active, saving database queries

Answer (score 6):

[Here's the algorithm (AFAIK) for the HNQ list.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/912736/hnq-algorithm) TL;DR: each question is assigned "arbitrary hotness points", based on this formula:

```
        MAX(10, AnswerCount) * QuestionScore
        ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
                   5 + AnswerScore
AHP = ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
         MIN(6, QuestionAgeHours + 1) ^ 1.4
```

That's already a significantly complex query to run, considering that it has to be done separately for each of the 160+ sites and the results collated, ordered, and cached. It's manageable at current levels, but that's because it can be done once every X (15, apparently - thanks Catija) minutes, cached, and forgotten about.

When you start introducing per-user customization, you start having to run a *different* query for every user. Even if that's just to filter down the list of hot questions you already have, that still means you suddenly have to run more, similarly complex, queries where you had to run none before. It's a performance hit that would take significant dev, DBA, and SRE time to manage, which is time that could be spent better on features that make a more tangible difference to the sites.

Comment: It's every 15 minutes, if it matters. ;)

Comment: If this query is already run on each of the 160+ sites every 15 minutes, I fail to see how it would cause additional trouble for the server using the system I described. The only additional work would just be to take the precomputed lists of questions every time a page is accessed, and do a quick slice operation on each of them, then randomly sprinkle a few in. Minus the database queries (I don't know how long those would take, but probably not too long), the calculations should take less than a millisecond per-user on any decent server (decent being better than my dual-core celeron laptop)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms It's not entirely clear how your proposed system works - but, from what I can gather, it works by issuing a whole _bunch_ of DB queries per user, not just one. That's not something you want to do on this scale, where you didn't have to do any previously. It's dev time better spent elsewhere.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I think you're misunderstanding the system. A list of some number (around 20) of question from each site with the highest AHP would be compiled every 15 minutes or so, then the user's preferences would be queried from the database and questions would be chosen from the precomputed lists based on these preferences.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms That's exactly the system I've described the drawbacks of in this post.

Comment: @ArtOfCode But, if you reload this page, you will see the HNQs aren't the exact same list for 15 minutes in a row. There's some computation being done to select a certain few. I see what you mean (potentially hundreds of lists being fetched each time), but some clever optimization (I'll explain some ideas in a minute in the main question) could make that a lot more manageable.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms The computation is that there are 100 HNQs selected every 15 minutes. All you're seeing is that 100 being randomly selected.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Okay, maybe you're right there, but I still think the system could be optimized well enough that each user would only need to wait a fraction of a second longer than usual, and active users could cache most of this to save time later. I'd think users don't usually read 1 question and leave, and if they did, the fraction of a second wouldn't matter much compared to the rest.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms _Could_ be optimized? Yes. With enough time, although you _will_ make a tradeoff somewhere - if you're caching, then it's in storage space, if you're not, it's in performance. Either way, this is a request that would take significant development time, which - given the general lack of interest in HNQ in general - is time that could be spent on more popular or more impactful features.

Comment: @ArtOfCode This feature could have an impact, by directing more experienced users toward questions they can actually contribute to. I'd think that's a major purpose for HNQs, and one that currently doesn't work. Showing C++ experts questions about cooking waffles probably isn't helping the question asker or the C++ expert. I've almost never found an HNQ I can contribute to, and it leads me to wonder why they even exist if they just sit there taking people's attention from why they're on the site.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms You're kinda missing the point though. Sure, this could have an impact. But, for the time we spend making this have an impact, we could make two other things that have a bigger impact.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms One of the major points of the HNQ is to bring the sites together somewhat. We like making users aware of the various sites we have. They may individually not have answers to questions but they might find the questions and their answers interesting. If we wanted more answers, we'd feature only (or primarily) unanswered questions. In fact, the opposite is the case - we **increase** the score if questions have many answers. It's about sharing complete knowledge. :)

Comment: @Catija Hmm, I guess I didn't realize the focus was more on that side of things. But I still think it might not make too much sense to share with a non-programmer complete knowledge on front-end web development, or to share complete knowledge on European laws with an American. (:

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms the other side of things is a cost-benefit analysis. How much time will implementing this take vs how many people would use it. People begged for a way to disable the HNQ for years. Fewer than 2k people have used it since we added it and it was a relatively simple change. There's tons of requests out there on our meta sites and we want to start working through them but I'd much rather implement a request that helps huge groups of people - updates to the graduation process or closing process - than something super niche that'd be cool but not essential.

Comment: Eventually we might look into letting people curate the sites in their HNQ list but there's tons of stuff higher up the list... like improving flagging or post locks.

Comment: @Catija True, I guess there are definitely other parts of SE that are in need of updates much more than HNQs. I guess this would be more of a "maybe someday this could be added" type feature request.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Those are always worth having around and welcome. Thanks for taking the time. But, don't think we don't care about The HNQ. It got a major revamp in February/March.